# Button created in interface builder... what is this dashed line and how do I fix it?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, interface-builder

This is a button created with interface builder:

[image]

What is this orange dashed line (button text area, right?), why this is outside the button and how do I make it be inside the button (if this is the case)???

Comment: It's because you have auto layout on and that's what it thinks the size and position should be based on the constraints. Sometimes it shows this when the element is moved or resized without adjusting constraints, other times it shows because the constraints given are ambiguous.

Comment: you are right! Please transform this comment in an answer, so I can accept!!!!! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you have auto layout on and that's what it thinks the size and position should be based on the constraints. Sometimes it shows this when the element is moved or resized without adjusting constraints, other times it shows because the constraints given are ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

Google auto layout. You haven't provided all the required constraints or they aren't the ones you want. The red box indicates where your button would be if it follows the provided constraints.

One possible fix: in interface builder, you see a few buttons on the bottom right. click the third one and then select update constraints.

Comment: update constraints has no effect. I have a label to the left side of that button. What I did was: on the label (control drag to left, add trailing space between label and container, control drag from label to button, add horizontal spacing - to prevent the label to grow over the button, control drag to left and add center label vertically), to button (control drag to right, add trailing space to container and center button vertically).

Comment: the only thing that does any effect is "update frame". In this case tue button size becomes the size of that red dashed rectangle, what is wrong.

Comment: You want horizontal spacing between the label and button. Trailing space is to the view itself. "Update frame" would indeed update the button to match the existing constraints. The opposite of what you want. It takes some practice to get the hang of it. Keep trying.  Try "clear constraints" and start over.  Also in the left part of the view (the tree view with all your interface elements), you'll see a yellow arrow next to the view/window if the constraints are invalid. That should provide some information. Also watch the WWDC video on auto layout. That helped me a lot.